# Call Function Through Implicit Function in Scala

Tags: scala, implicit

In Scala, if I have a class called `Vector2D` and I want to make some implicit conversions for it. Currently, I have this function placed in the `Vector2D`: `implicit def fromFloatTuple(tuple: (Float, Float)): Vector2D = new Vector2D(tuple._1, tuple._2)`

I can do the following successfully `val x: Vector2D = (1f, 1f)`. However, I cannot do something like: `val x: Float = (1f, 1f).length()` (obviously length is defined for Vector2D). Why does this not work, I would expect it to be converted to something like `val x: Float = fromFloatTuple((1f, 1f)).length()` but it is not. How do I get this effect in Scala?

Also now that I think of it, how could I make this function accept other numerical types as well without making a function for each combination of all numerical types (not a problem with a 2D vector but quite unclean for a 4D vector).

Answer (score 1):

When you have target or source type `Vector2D`, the compiler looks in the companion object of `Vector2D`; in `val x: Float = (1f, 1f).length()` it doesn't. Looking for all possible types for implicit conversion would slow compilation very much, and Scala compiler is already slow (though improving).

You need to bring `fromFloatTuple` into scope by importing it:

```
import your.package.Vector2D._ // or just fromFloatTuple instead of _
```

Answer (score -1):

[This is exactly how it is supposed to work](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/RGEuv1g/4):

```
import scala.language.implicitConversions

object Test {
  class Vector2D(x: Float, y: Float) { def length(): Float = x + y }

  implicit def fromFloatTuple(tuple: (Float, Float)): Vector2D = Vector2D(tuple._1, tuple._2)

  val x: Float = (1f, 1f).length()
```

For the more generic case you might want to look at [scala.math.Numeric](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/math/Numeric.html).

```
  case class Vector4D[N](a: N, b: N, c: N, d: N)(implicit n: Numeric[N]) {
    import n._

    def length(): N = a + b + c + d
  }

  implicit def c2V4D[N: Numeric](tup: (N, N, N, N)): Vector4D[N] = new Vector4D(tup._1, tup._2, tup._3, tup._4)

  println(Vector4D(1,2,3,4).length())
  println(Vector4D(1,2,3,4.5).length())
  println((1,2,3,4).length())
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16747601)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: This fails for a case like `(1f, 1)` as they are of different numerical types. A workaround though would be to declare multiple generic arguments.

Comment: Ah, I misread - you want to have different types per argument?
I doubt it will be that easy then, because Scala does not perform multiple implicit searches in a row.